# Should label elements exclude formatting for screen-readers

Tags: html, accessibility, screen-readers

Does including formatting within a `<label>` element have any positive or negative effect on screen readers (or any other disability support equipment)?

For example, would either of the following cause issues?

```
<label for="txtName"><b>Name:</b></label> <input type="text" id="txtName"/>

<label><b>Name:</b> <input type="text" id="txtName"/></label>
```

Or should it be...

```
<b><label for="txtName">Name:</label></b> <input type="text" id="txtName"/>

<b><label>Name: <input type="text" id="txtName"/></label></b>
```

Does it make any difference?

Comment: If this is supposed to have a pure visual effect, then why not  make it to be _actual_ formatting (meaning: CSS) in the first place …?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @CBroe, but I wasn't asking for better ways of formatting, I was asking how the code effects screen-readers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this doesn't affect screen readers in any way. Screen readers ignore attributes such as bold by default, but they can be set to speak and/or indicate them in Braille.